# Image generated after building drawing cache always gives 72 px/inch resolution but I need 300 px/inch resolution

Tags: android, drawingcache

Please guide me regarding with this problem. Actually I changed the layout's size and ImageView's size but even that it gave me 72 px/inch. what should I go for to get expected resolution.

Thanks in advance.